# Just curious - ParcelFileDescriptor's getStatSize() returns file size in MB not MiB, why is Google making this complicated?

Tags: java, android, parcelfiledescriptor

Phone's File manager shows the size of a randomly selected image as 7.09 MB.
Android's ParcelFileDescriptor's  getStatSize() method returns 7093426 bytes. This number is exactly equal to 7.09 something when you divide by 1,000,000, not 1,048,576.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = this.getApplicationContext()
.getContentResolver()
.openFileDescriptor(a_valid_uri, "r");
long size = pfd.getStatSize(); // this returns file size and equals 7093426
```

Why in the world would Google want to return the file size in MB as in the Base10 one instead of the MiB - Base2 style, when the Android developers have to deal with the MiB style format 1024, 2048 etc?

Even though the conversion is simple, isn't this extra headache to convert this for byte buffers that depend on Base2 format for our Buffered input/output since the software Input/output stream knows to read/write in Base2 style only?